# unable to get filename from argv[1] in C

Tags: c, string, input

I'm trying to make a program which makes a copy of the file you put in, only then with a reversed filename (eg. input.txt = txt.tupni). 
I start my program with

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

When I use `printf("%s",argv[1])` I can see the file name which has been put in. However, when I try to manipulate it I can't get it to work. 
`char name = argv[1]` doesnt work,
neither does `char name[] = argv[1]` work

All I want is either a char array or a piece of malloc memory which has all of the characters.

Comment: You're assigning a `char[]` to a `char`. Strings can't be stored in a single character.

Comment: For starter `char name = argv[1]` can't work because you're assigning a string to a char.

Comment: @trivalent maybe OP is new to C – there's no reason to be harsh (although reading K&R is always a good first step to picking up the language!)

Comment: @OlivierGrech ..assignig a pointer to a char....

Comment: i am indeed new to programming with C, sorry for that. Where can i find the K&R and what is it? Thanks for the tip and help!

Comment: @KeesdeGroot K&R is the nickname of the book describing the specification of the C language (its authors were Brian **K**ernighan and Dennis **R**itchie – hence the nickname; the actual title is _The C Programming Language_). The second edition is the latest available, and describes the C89 standard, which is a good place to start despite its age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`argv` is of type `char **`, so `argv[1]` is of type `char *`.  So that's the type of the variable you want to assign this to.

```
char *name = argv[1];
```

You can't declare `name` as `char []` and initialize it with a `char *`.  Only a string literal may be used for initialization.

If you want to make a copy of the string rather than have another pointer to it, you can use `strdup` which allocates memory for the copied string and copies it over.

```
char *name = strdup(argv[1]);
```

Don't forget to `free` it when you're done with it.

Comment: Yeah, OP, just remember a 'C-style string' is just an array of characters, and the name (identifier [variable name]) of that array is a pointer to the first character of that string (hence the type `char *`), and in this case the 'name' of the string (character array) is `argv[1]`. So, with `argv`, you have an array of these strings, so `argv` itself is a pointer to the first string (which happens to be in the same location/have the same memory address as the first character of the first string [`argv[0]`]), so that is why `argv` is type `char **`.

Comment: And also, OP, don't forget that you can't assign strings (if you want a copy; it works in this case because `name` is essentially an alias for `argv[1]`), so if you want a _new_ string that has the same data, you would do `#include <string.h>` `strcpy(name, argv[1])` (or `strncpy()`), as long as `name` is large enough. Make sure there's enough room for the null byte.

Comment: I started programming in C the day before yesterday, so thanks a ton for the help and tips! Do you know any place to practice with or read about the double-pointer thingy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function like `strcpy` to accomplish this, as well as know the string length.

Here's what you do:

```
int len = strlen(argv[1])
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
if(buffer != NULL)
{
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    // copy the file etc.
}
```